Yandex-static-maps-api позволяют получить только фотоплан (фотоснимок)?
Всем доброго дня.
Можно ли с помощью Yandex-static-maps-api получить только фотоснимок указанного координатами фрагмента в нужном масштабе (без самой карты, улиц, дорог, названий и т.д.) - только спутниковый снимок?
